# Group by month and year in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have query on postgresql and I want to implement in my apps using rails

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows("SELECT to_char(date,'Mon') as mon, extract(year from date) as yyyy, SUM(CASE WHEN Title = 4 THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS sold FROM Transactions WHERE Store_id = 5 AND Product_id = 2 GROUP BY 1,2")
```

I tried on rails console, and result is :

```
←[1m←[36m (2.0ms)←[0m  ←[1m
SELECT to_char(date,'Mon') as mon, extract(year from date) as yyyy, SUM(CASE WHEN Title = 4 THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS sold FROM Transactions WHERE Store_id = 5 AND Product_id = 2 GROUP BY 1,2 
←[0m=> [["Jul", "2013", "113"], ["Oct", "2013", "73"], ["Jun", "2013", "291"], ["Sep", "2013", "13"], [" Aug", "2013", "81"]]
```

The result not order by month-year.

I tried to add `ORDER BY 1,2` but the result looks like :

```
←[1m←[36m (10.0ms)←[0m  ←[1m
SELECT to_char(date,'Mon') as mon, extract(year from date) as yyyy, SUM(CASE WHEN Title = 4 THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS sold FROM Transactions WHERE Store_id = 5 AND Product_id = 2 GROUP BY 1,2 ORDER BY 1,2
←[0m=> [["Aug", "2013", "81"], ["Jul", "2013", "113"], ["Jun", "2013", "291"], ["Oct", "2013", "73"], ["Sep", "2013", "13"]]
```

Why the result not ordering by month and year?

I think this order by "alphabetical" not date..

Answer (score 14):

I'm doing this on Rails 5.0.1 (confirmed working on 6.1.3.2 too) with PostgreSQL:

```rb
User.
where('created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', start, finish).
group('(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at))::integer').
group('(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at))::integer').
order('2 DESC, 3 DESC').count
```

Which produces this:

```rb
{
  [2017, 2]=>1908,
  [2017, 1]=>5910,
  [2016, 12]=>6299,
  [2016, 11]=>5717,
  [2016, 10]=>5912,
  [2016, 9]=>6098,
  [2016, 8]=>5897,
  [2016, 7]=>5896,
  [2016, 6]=>5902,
  [2016, 5]=>6279,
  [2016, 4]=>5510,
  [2016, 3]=>5323,
  [2016, 2]=>5139,
  [2016, 1]=>4293
}
```

For MySQL:

```rb
User.
where('created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', start, finish).
group('YEAR(created_at)').
group('MONTH(created_at)').
order('2 DESC, 3 DESC').count
```

Comment: what type of data is that response? I'm grabbing this data for a graphQL response, but I'm not sure what data type the above is. Shouldn't there be a column/field name for "period" and then the result is in count value?

Comment: @NathanLeggatt It's a simple ruby hash, the keys are arrays [year (int), month (int)] and the values ints. Since we're grouping and counting Rails doesn't know how to build models from the query results and returns this instead.

Comment: @NathanLeggatt If I were using it for an API response, I'd turn the years into hashes and nest the months inside the years as keys and the count as values: `{ 2017 => { 2 => 1908, 1 => 5910 }, 2016 => { 12 => 6299 } }`.

You could use this to do the transformation:

`response = result.each_with_object({}) { |((year, month), count), hash| hash[year] ||= {}; hash[year][month] = count }`

Answer (score 2):

**For newer versions of Postgres**

Take a look at example E of this tutorial -> https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-group-by/

You need to add the function on the `.group` calling also:

```rb
    Model.select(
      "date_trunc('month', created_at)"
    ).group(
      "date_trunc('month', created_at)"
    )
```

Altough date_trunc seems to be faster, you can also group it using to_char so you can configure your output string:

```rb
    Model.select(
      "to_char(created_at, 'MM/YYYY')"
    ).group(
      "to_char(created_at, 'MM/YYYY')"
    )
```

In my case I added a sort, a count, and called to_char only on the select to get a prettier result:

```rb
    Order.select(
      <<-SQL
        to_char(date_trunc('month', created_at), 'MM/YYYY') AS month,
        COUNT(id) as number_of_orders
      SQL
    ).group(
      "date_trunc('month', created_at)"
    ).order(
      "date_trunc('month', created_at)"
    )
```

( The `<<-SQL` is just a [Heredoc](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/11/ruby-heredoc/) )

Answer (score 1):

I think my current query order by "alphabetical" not date..

`to_char(date,'Mon')`

This is query for group by month and year and then order by month and year

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows("SELECT date_part('month', date), date_part('year', date), SUM(CASE WHEN Title = 4 THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS sold FROM Transactions WHERE Store_id = 5 AND Product_id = 2 GROUP BY date_part('month', date), date_part('year', date) ORDER BY date_part('month', date), date_part('year', date)")
```

And the result looks like :

```
←[1m←[36m (3.0ms)←[0m  ←[1m
SELECT date_part('month', date), date_part('year', date), SUM(CASE WHEN Title = 4 THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS sold FROM Transactions WHERE Store_id = 5 AND Product_id = 2 GROUP BY date_part('month', date), date_part('year', date) ORDER BY date_part('
month', date), date_part('year', date)
←[0m=> [["6", "2013", "291"], ["7", "2013", "113"], ["8", "2013", "81"], ["9", "2013", "13"], ["10", "2013", "73"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

this query get data from `transactions` table group by month and year, order by month in `ASC` which is default if not mention order

```
Transactions.select("DATE_TRUNC('month', date) AS month_year, SUM(CASE WHEN title = 4 THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS sold").where("store_id = 5 AND product_id = 2").group("month_year")
```